# Facebook News.Reads Actions

Tags: facebook-graph-api

News.reads api fails.

I using curl php.
Error Code:

> {"error":{"message":"(#100) The Action Type news:Read is not approved,
>   so app xxxx can only publish to administrators, developers, and
>   testers of the app. User xxxx is not one of those
>   roles.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the error message. It says that Facebook has not approved your `Read` action so it won't be added to Facebook, unless the user is a Admin, Developer or Tester of the app.

Try posting the read action as the administrator / developer of the application.